# How can I typeset this correspondence in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, math-mode, arrows

I am looking to create a "table" or something similar in LaTeX where I show correspondence/mapping between a natural number and some other natural number, as indicated in the picture below (please excuse the badly drawn Paint example):

[image]

In other words "one maps onto zero, two maps onto one..." etc. I am, however, not sure how to do so in LaTeX.

Can anyone please provide me with some help as to how I can go about typesetting something similar to this in a LaTeX environment?

Comment: Use a tabular (text) or array (math) and $\updownarrow$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option using a `matrix`; an `array` could also be used, but with `matrix` you don't have to specify the number and format of columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\updownarrow & \updownarrow & \updownarrow  \\
2 & 3 & 1 
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As has been noted, the vertical space around the arrows seems a little uneven: there's more space above the arrows than below them, so one can easily fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\UpDownarrow[1][0.2ex]{
  \raisebox{#1}[0pt][0pt]{$\updownarrow$}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\UpDownarrow & \UpDownarrow & \UpDownarrow \\
2 & 3 & 1 
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record, the `array` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
\updownarrow & \updownarrow & \updownarrow  \\
2 & 3 & 1 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: ... except that the vertical space looks wrong: the space above the arrows seems larger than the space below the arrows. Or is it an illusion?

Comment: @lhf No, it's not an illusion but it can be easily fixed, if desired. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Dillon You're welcome. I updated my answer with an improved version that might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 9):

This might seem an overkill, but may be a good way of generalization.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[name=m,matrix of math nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=1em]
      {0 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 \\};
    \draw[<->] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-1);
    \draw[<->] (m-1-2) -- (m-2-2);
    \draw[<->] (m-1-3) -- (m-2-3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: If you load `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` it will probably give better arrowheads by default.

Comment: This is certainly not overkill. :). It's always good to share another possibility of solving a problem :)

Comment: I meant because `tikz` is a huge package, but this will definitely provide a lot of flexibility.

Comment: I feel like this has better spacing somehow. …The top and bottom spaces seem to be more even than `matrix` answer.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another `tikz` solution, but here I use a `\foreach` loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\aestrut{\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{2ex}}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={anchor=base}]
    \foreach[count=\myi from 0] \mya/\myb in {0/1,1/2,2/3,h/g,e/j,j/k}
    {
      \node[my node] (A\myi) at (\myi,1) {\aestrut\mya};
      \node[my node] (B\myi) at (\myi,0) {\aestrut\myb};
      \draw[arrows=<->] (A\myi) -- (B\myi);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is a bit to set up, but once it's been set up it's very easy to add or remove pairs from the correspondence:  just add (or remove) the pair from the `in {.....}` group where the pairs are separated by `/`.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your intended use, a TABstack may offer certain advantages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine,xcolor}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
While a TABstack can be used in a math environment
\[
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1}
\]
it can also be used inline: 
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1}
\\with differing vertical alignments
\tabbedLongstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1} 
or 
\tabbedLongunderstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1},\\
with different horizontal gap%
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1},
placed in a box 
\fbox{\,%
  \tabbedCenterstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1}}\\
or saved%
\savestack\mybox{%
  \tabbedCenterstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\2&3&1}}
for repeated use: \mybox, \fbox{\,\mybox}, \mybox.\\
Or with annotation:
\tabbedCenterstack[l]{0&1&2\\\updownarrow&\updownarrow&\updownarrow\\%
  2\bllap{\color{red}\tiny\mbox{This is important}\uparrow}&3%
  &\brlap{\color{red}\uparrow\tiny\mbox{but not this}}1
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pstricks}

\def\Map(#1)#2#3{%
  \psline{<->}(#1,0)(#1,1)
  \rput(#1,-0.3){#2}
  \rput(#1,1.3){#3}}

% parameter
\def\arrows{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0.95,-0.4)(\arrows.05,1.4) % boundry found manually
  \multido{\iA = 0+1, \iB = 1+1}{\arrows}{\Map(\iB){$\iA$}{$\iB$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is choose the value of `\arrows` and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution with [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.7em, every arrow/.append style={<->}]
    1\arrow{d} & 2\arrow{d} & 3\arrow{d} \\
    0 & 1 & 2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A MetaPost way of doing this:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps";

input latexmp; setupLaTeXMP(options = "12pt", textextlabel = enable, mode = rerun);

% t[] values on top, b[] values on bottom
% u spacing between columns, v arrows length
vardef corresp(suffix t, b)(expr u, v) =
    save i; numeric i; i = 1;
    forever:
        exitif (unknown t[i]) or (unknown b[i]);
        drawdblarrow ((i-1)*u, 0) -- ((i-1)*u, v);
        label.top("$" & decimal t[i] & "$", ((i-1)*u, v)); 
        label.bot("$" & decimal b[i] & "$", ((i-1)*u, 0));
        i := i+1;
    endfor
enddef; 

% The OP's example
beginfig(1);
    numeric u, v, t[], b[]; u = 0.75cm; v = 0.75cm; 
    for i = 1 upto 3: b[i] = i-1; t[i] = i; endfor
    corresp(t, b)(u, v);
endfig;

% A bigger example
beginfig(2);
    numeric u, v, t[], b[]; u = cm; v = cm; 
    for i = 1 upto 7: t[i] = i-1; b[i] = (i-1)**2; endfor
    corresp(t, b)(u, v);
endfig;

end.
```

Horizontal spacing `u` between numbers can be adjusted at will, as for the arrows length `v`. As many numbers as wished at the top and the bottom can be entered, respectively in the arrays `t[]` and `b[]`. The `corresp` macro takes care of the subsequent job.

The code is supposed to be compiled by MetaPost with LaTeX as typesetting engine.

```
mpost --tex=latex program.mp
```

Two figures are produced by this code: The first one is the OP's example, the second one is another (bigger) example.

[image]

[image]